# How can I retain selected images in form if submitted form invalid?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I try to attach a few images to the Symfony form. If submitted form invalid, the entered text persist, but images lose.

How can I retain selected images if submitted form invalid?

P.S. I need to use form submitting without `Ajax` and images should locating with text fields in same form.

Comment: you can't. uploaded files which aren't dealt with are simply deleted by php when the script exits. you'd need to capture/save the images somewhere, or just re-upload the files when the "fixed" form is resubmitted.

Comment: @MarcB Have you any best practice (or not best practice, at least) solution for it? Could you suggest it, if you have?

Comment: move the files into a temp dir, make a note of them soemwhere, then display the form again "you failed to do X, I've saved your uploads while you fix X...", then grab the files out of the temp dir when the (correct) form is submitted.

Comment: @MarcB How long upload files could placed in temp dir? When they clean up from there?

Comment: that's up to you. php's own upload temp dir has the file only for the life of the current script run, unless you take steps to move the file elsewhere. it'd be up to you to establish a second level temp dir and clean it up if the user abandons the form.

Comment: @MarcB OK, I understand, thanks a lot. I will try to use this solution.